# Как проверить правильность работы SSL сертификата?

Tags: apache, ssl, сертификат, openssl

Установил ssl сертификат на сервер apache, какими способами можно проверить правильность работы сертификата и на что следует обращать внимание при проверке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Free online service SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)

Comment: проверка по этому сервису выдает в отчете следующее: overall rating "C",  SSL 3  INSECURE, POODLE (SSLv3) Vulnerable INSECURE

Comment: Значит проблемы с безопасностью. Посмотри на свой отчёт, посмотри все выделенные строчки (оранжевым и т.п.), почитай все "MORE INFO" и исправляй. Будет полезно посмотреть как выглядят отчёты с рейтингом А и А+. Ну а про уязвимость ssl3 вообще полный гугл информации, например http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-poodle-ssl/

Comment: https://sslcheck.globalsign.com так же мне понравился этот сайт, выдает достаточно подробный отчет после проверки.

Comment: норм... но я тебе дал ссылку на Qualys ssl labs, а в подвале твоей ссылки пишут "основано на технологиях Qualys ssl labs", так что разница лишь в компоновке отчёта и языке. не слишком существенная

Comment: ясно, думал это независимые сайты.